# Is there a way to define a template member in a non-template class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Say I have a class template named `Compute`, and another class named `Function_A` with a member function template:

```
template <typename T> void Evaluate(T parameter)
```

I am constrained to use the class `Function_A` as it is. I already know that `T` can only be one of two types `type_1` and `type_2`.

Is there a way to have something similar to `Compute<T> C` as a member variable of `Function_A` instead of defining a local `Compute<T>` object inside `Evaluate(...)`? I know that this is against the philosophy of using templates, hence it is likely not possible, but can ideally be done in that case instead?

I tried to have two members `Compute<type_1> C1` and `Compute<type_2> C2` in `Function_A`, and then use them under an `if (typeid(T) == typeid(type_1))` but it's a pretty hideous, and against the philosophy of using templates as well.

Just to illustrate what I mean:

```
template <class T>
class Compute
{
public:
  T Function_B(T parameter)
    {
      return f.eval(parameter);
    }

private:
  SomeClass<T> f;
}
```

And a class:

```
class Function_A
{
  public:
    template <typename T> T Evaluate(T parameter)
    {
      Compute<T> C; //this is very expensive!
      T value = C.Function_B(parameter);
      return value;
    }

  private:
    double SomeParameter;
    //Compute<T> C; //conceptually what I want
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about (untested):

```
class Function_A
{
  public:
    template <typename T> void Evaluate(T parameter)
    {
      T value = std::get<Compute<T>>(computers).Function_B(parameter);
      return T(SomeParameter) * value;
    }

  private:
    double SomeParameter;
    std::tuple<Compute<type_1>, Compute<type_2>> computers;
};
```

Note: `std::pair` would work exactly the same as `std::tuple` here, if you fancy the first/second semantics it adds.

Additionally, note that `T(SomeParameter)` is a C-style cast, which could be problematic if `T` is not a class type. Consider `T{}` or `static_cast<T>()`.

Comment: Tested or not, me likes the use of the standard library to solve this

Comment: @StoryTeller of course, I'm not some kind of savage :)

Comment: Why use `std::tuple` over `std::pair` (the latter also has [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get) support)? I agree that `std::tuple` it fits the design in principle (nothing about this is specific to having exactly two types) but I would find it worth some discussion.

Comment: @MaxLanghof well, what you said. There's no inherent "first" or "second" in there as far as the question goes, so `tuple` it was.

Comment: Oh, and using a `static_cast` would be better than `T(SomeParameter)`. I was stuck trying to figure out what pointer you are dereferencing for a moment.

Comment: I've been struggling with this a lot: while this works perfectly for `type_i` having std members and containers, it doesn't for user-defined types. I am getting the following error `error: no matching function for call to 'get' candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter '_Jp' `. The second answer below works out of the box at the moment. I would still consider this answer neater, but need to understand what's the problem.

Comment: @Rabah nothing I've written depends on what the contents of the tuple are. In particular, `std::get` is called on the tuple itself and has no reason to fail. Did you forget to include `<tuple>` maybe? Otherwise, please provide me with a link to the failing code.

Comment: @Quentin, Thanks for your help, I've tried your answer in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894345/is-there-a-way-to-define-a-template-member-in-a-non-template-class-2 I am still getting an error, but would be happy to make this method you're proposing work.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is make `C` `static`.  If you have

```
template <typename T> void Evaluate(T parameter)
{
  static Compute<T> C; // only do this once per T now
  T value = C.Function_B(parameter);
  return T(SomeParameter)*value;
}
```

then when you call `Evaluate` with `type_1` you'll have one version of the function that has `C<type_1>` in it that will only be constructed the first time the function is called and the same thing happens for `type_2`.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll have to think about shared state and thread safety with this solution. Every `Evaluate<T>` call, even from different `Function_A` objects, will use the same `Compute<T>` object.

Comment: @Kevin same is true on a per-object-level for having a `Compute<T>` as member which is what OP intially wanted

Comment: @user463035818 In that case each `Function_A` object gets its own `Compute<T>`. Here there's only 1 `Compute<T>` (per `T`) shared across all `Function_A` objects. It's not necessarily a problem, but it needs to be considered.

Comment: @user463035818 Although in that case you can mitigate the concerns by having different `Function_A` for each thread.  My solution forces all threads to share an object, so it is something to consider.

Comment: The problem works out of the box with this solution, see my above comment.