# Is there a way to define a template member in a non-template class? #2

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template class `class_A`:

```cpp
// class_A.h
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <class T>
class class_A
{
public:
    class_A(){}

    T Function_A(T parameter)
    {
        return parameter;
    }
};
```

that I am trying to use in a non-template class `class_B` as private member:

```cpp
// class_B.h
#pragma once

#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

#include "class_A.h"

class class_B
{
public:
    class_B();

    template <typename T> T Evaluate(T parameter);

private:
    std::tuple<class_A<double>, class_A<char> > As;
};
```

and

```cpp
// class_B.cc
#include "class_B.h"

class_B::class_B(){}

template <typename T>
T class_B::Evaluate(T parameter)
{
    return std::get<class_A<T>>(As).Function_A(parameter); //This is causing error
    //return parameter // This works
}

template double class_B::Evaluate(double parameter);
template char class_B::Evaluate(char parameter);
```

and my `main.cc` is:

```cpp
// main.cc
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include "class_B.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    class_B B;

    std::cout<< B.Evaluate(5.2) <<std::endl;
    std::cout << B.Evaluate('h') << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
src/class_B.cc:8:12: error: no matching function for call to 'get'
    return std::get<class_A<T>>(As).Evaluate(parameter);
.
.
.
etc.
```

This is a trial of the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357742/9203360 that didn't work, but would be ideal if it did.

Comment: templates are header only, no cc file!

Comment: @OblivionreinstateOurMonica, yes `class_A` is template class hence it's header only, but not `class_B`.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel The template is explicitly instantiated for the relevant types, see e.g. `template double class_B::Evaluate(double parameter);`.

Comment: Are you compiling against C++14 or higher? (Required for your use of `std::get`)

Comment: Indeed, this is one part of the problem, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the overload of `std::get` taking a type as template argument and returning the tuple element of that type is available only since C++14.

Per your comment you were not compiling against C++14 or later and so there was no match for `std::get` with a type as first template argument.

Answer (score 1):

The

> std::get< class_A< T>>(As)

get an instance of class_A, so you can't call the Evaluate Method, doesn't exist. You should call method Function_A, or define Evaluate method in class_A

```
return std::get<class_A<T>>(As).Function_A(parameter); // Call Function_A
```

It works in Visual Studio 2015 - Windows Platform 10.0.17763.0

Plus you need c++14 for `std::get` to work.

Comment: This is true, but not what the error message is complaining about. I assume that OP meant to name `Function_A` instead `Evaluate`.

Comment: you're right it's a stupid mistake... actually @uneven_mark's answer was the thing I'm missing